# Add watermark to pdf java iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, watermark

I want to add a image or text watermark to pdf file. I found some examples online, but my case is a little bit different.

I have an existing pdf template which is already populated with dynamic data and converted to byte[]. This generated bytes are later exported to pdf.

I would like to add the watermark to that generated bytes. 
Something like:

```
byte[] addWatermark(byte[] generatedBytes){
  byte[] bytesWithWatermark;

  //add watermark to bytes

  return bytesWithWatermark;
}
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to do this with iText.

Comment: Just feed the byte[] into a stream and use that stream to feed into a `PdfReader`. Create a `PdfStamper` with a different byte output stream, apply watermark using the example you found and return the bytes from the outputstream after closing the PdfStamper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you already have examples for applying watermarks using iText. As you already have a PDF, you should use code from an example that adds watermarks to *existing* PDFs. This should be an example that works with a `PdfReader` / `PdfStamper` pair, e.g. those [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/watermark-examples), which all have the structure

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOME_SOURCE);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, SOME_TARGET_STREAM);
[... add watermark to all pages in stamper ...]
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

To make these example fit into your `addWatermark` method, simply use your `byte[]` instead of `SOME_SOURCE` and a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `SOME_TARGET_STREAM`:

```
byte[] addWatermark(byte[] generatedBytes) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream target  = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(generatedBytes);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, target);
        [... add watermark to all pages in stamper ...]
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
        return target.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

**PS** As you used only the tag [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) and not the tag [itext7](/questions/tagged/itext7), I assumed you were looking for a solution for iText 5.5.x. But the same principle as applied here, i.e. using your `byte[]` as source argument and a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as target argument, will also allow you to make iText 7.x examples fit into your method frame.